# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function React Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I have a problem with React when I try to change the page through the button (but) the console gives me:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or >a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You >likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

But when I put the `onClick` code in the class code it shows the jsx code. So it works but why do I still get the error? Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

//sass
require('../sass/style.scss');

var pages = ['Qrscan'];
var jsx = [<Qrscan />];

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {target: <Menu />};
        App.changePage = App.changePage.bind(this);
    }

    static changePage (tar) {
       this.setState({target: tar});
    }

    render () {
        return (
          this.state.target
        )
    }
}


//Rendering
class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="root">
                <Header />
                <div className="container">
                    <But target="Qrscan" class="button button-QR" text="Use QR code" type="button" linkTo="" />
                    <But class="button button-URL" text="Use URL" type="button" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Qrscan extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>test</h1>
        )
    }
}

//elements
class Header extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <div className="header-logo">Jukey</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class But extends React.Component {
    getInfo () {
        for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            if(pages[i] == this.props.target) {
                return jsx[i];
            }
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => App.changePage(this.getInfo())} className={this.props.class}>{this.props.text}</button>
        )
    }
}

render (<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me with my problems!

Comment: Is this all in one file? Also, post the last sentence of the error, as in "check the render function of ..."

Comment: @AndrewLi yes this is all in one file and this is all I get form the error all the other things are redirects nothing like you said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ES6 Class declarations are [not hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

In your second line when you defined `var jsx = [<Qrscan />];`, that element is actually `undefined`. When I print out the contents of the `jsx` array, I get:

```
Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: undefined, key: null, ref: null, props: Object…}
```

So you simply have to shift that `jsx` array declaration to **after** your `<Qrscan>` component declaration.

Refer to the following JSFiddle for the fix and see for yourself that it works after shifting the declaration order (:

```js
var pages = ['Qrscan'];

//Rendering
class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="root">
                <Header />
                <div className="container">
                    <But target="Qrscan" class="button button-QR" text="Use QR code" type="button" linkTo="" />
                    <But class="button button-URL" text="Use URL" type="button" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {target: <Menu />};
        App.changePage = App.changePage.bind(this);
    }

    static changePage (tar) {
       this.setState({target: tar});
    }

    render () {
        return (
          this.state.target
        )
    }
}

class Qrscan extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>test</h1>
        )
    }
}

var jsx = [<Qrscan />];

//elements
class Header extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <div className="header-logo">Jukey</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class But extends React.Component {
    getInfo () {
        for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            if (pages[i] == this.props.target) {
                return jsx[i];
            }
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => App.changePage(this.getInfo())} className={this.props.class}>{this.props.text}</button>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render (<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```